# getting the same value multiple times with base case in recursion

Tags: javascript, loops, recursion

```js
//aim -> Given a number n, return the number of steps required to reach 1.
//ex -> when n=12, we get 9 steps


// export 
const steps = (num) => {
  //function to check if the number is positive integer
  isValid=n=>n>0;
  

  if(isValid(num)){
    //base case -> the number becomes 1
    if(num===1){
      return 1;
    }
    //if the number is not equal to 1
    else{
      //if the number is even do n/2 and return it again
      if(num%2===0){
        return steps(num/2);
      }
      else{

        return steps(3*num+1);
      }
    }
  }

};
console.log( steps(12) )
/**
 * lets do with recursion:
 * take an input num
 * if the number is 1, return 1 (base case)
 * if the number is not 1 but even, do cal=num/2  and return step(cal) back to the function
 * if the number is not 1 bu odd, do cal = 3*num+1
 */
```

when i console log the isEven, i get 1-> 3 times and when i do isOdd console.log, i get it a lot of times.

what's wrong here? how can i prevent it in the future? thank you!

Comment: This is a great opportunity to familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger.  Using your browser's debugging tools you can place a breakpoint to pause the execution of the code and step through that execution line by line, stepping into called functions, etc., observing the changing values of your variables.  When you do this, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: "*when i console log the isEven, i get 1-> 3 times and when i do isOdd console.log, i get it a lot of times.*" [seems to work just fine](https://jsbin.com/kayomet/edit?js,console). I don't see what you think the problem is.

Comment: from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) *starting with n = 12, one gets the sequence 12, 6, 3, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1* - so there are three odd numbers in that sequence.  Maybe you are seeing that in your isOdd console.log, which is not shown in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see for yourself: your case only takes calculated values into account and does not count the number of steps

```js
const cl = (n, op ,v )=> console.log(`${n} -->${op} =  ${v}`)

const steps = num =>
  {
  if(num > 0)
    {
    if (num===1) { cl(1,'-',1);  return 1 }
    else
      {
      if (num%2===0) { cl(num, 'n/2',   num/2  );  return steps(num/2)   }
      else           { cl(num, '3*n+1', 3*num+1);  return steps(3*num+1) }
      }
    }
  else return 'invalid num'
  }
  
console.log( 'steps(12) =', steps(12) )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0 }
```

a "correct" solution :

```js
const stepsCount = (num, step=0) =>
  {
  step++
  if(num > 0)
    {
    if (num===1)  return step 
    else
      {
      if (num%2===0) return stepsCount(num/2,   step)   
      else           return stepsCount(3*num+1, step) 
      }
    }
  else return 'invalid num'
  }
 
console.log( 'stepsCount(12) =', stepsCount(12) )
```

Comment: I see. So all it was missing was a step counter? anything else that i can do to improvce my recursion understanding and try to alleviate such errors? thank you!

Comment: @ShahidAlam I cannot say, there are sometimes psychological blockages which prevent us from moving forward on technical points (emotional pb). the best way is practice, exercises ...

Answer (score 0):

The result of your log is the output of the last iteration of the called function.
If track `num` through this function you will get all the iterations

```
const steps = (num) => {
 //function to check if the number is positive integer
 isValid=n=>n>0;
 console.log("e",num);

 if(isValid(num)){
 //base case -> the number becomes 1
 if(num===1){
  return 1;
 }
 //if the number is not equal to 1
 else{
  //if the number is even do n/2 and return it again
  if(num%2===0){
    return steps(num/2);
  }
  else{

    return steps(3*num+1);
  }
 }
}

};
console.log( steps(12) );
```

Comment: anything i can do to improve my understanding of recursion? thank you!

Comment: Imagine a bubble, you are outside of this bubble and you can't see what's happening inside of it. your function is a guy with a list of thing to do and he's inside that bubble. If you phonecall that guy and tell him "do you list and tell me when you've done" the guy will do his list and ONLY when it's done he will tells you. Even if one of these tasks is "note to myself: Do the list again", since the job is not done, he can't tells you. So you have to put in his list "here: tells my boss the status of my job"